# What is the most accurate/granular Python3 timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timestamp, high-resolution-clock

What is the most accurate timestamp in Python3?

Associated question: would it make sense to write a little timestamp program in C and invoke it from Python, or perhaps use C++'s `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`? Thx, Keith :^)

Comment: Even with a C program, wouldn't you still depend on what the OS provides?

Answer (score 1):

python's `datetime` package has both `datetime` and `time` classes, which are accurate to microseconds. A small demonstration:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> elements = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'microsecond']
>>> for element in elements:
>>>     print(f'{element}: {getattr(d,element)}')
year: 2020
month: 5
day: 29
hour: 11
minute: 48
second: 48
microsecond: 979449
```

Hope this helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: Unfortunately having a microsecond attribute doesn't tell you anything about the expected accuracy or resolution of that attribute.  In fact it might depend on the OS you're running on.